# PHP Get Returned Value From Constructor

Tags: php, class, constructor

I am confused, I have a PHP class with a constructor:

```
class Test {
   public function __construct() {
      return "some text";
   }
}
```

Then I instanciate an object:

```
$t = new Test();
```

I would expect the contents of $t to be "some text":

```
print_r($t);
```

But it is:

```
Test Object
(
)
```

How do I get the returned value `"some text"` from the constructor?

Comment: "some test" isn't stored anywhere and is lost as soon as the constructer is done running

Comment: You don't. Constructor only returns an instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [returning a value in constructor function of a class, PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class-php)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `return` anything from a constructor. The `new` keyword will always result in a new object, it does not matter what you `return` from the constructor.

Comment: So if I want to return an error case in the constructor how is that done?

Comment: If you want to prevent the object from being instantiated, `throw` an exception.