# How the return the value from constructor and and pass the value to another user defined function

Tags: php

i have this constructor __construct()

```
class MxpCms_Admin {

    public function __construct()
    {       
        global $MxpDatabase;

        $Qcmsdrag = $MxpDatabase->query('select t.id from :table_templates t, :table_configuration c where t.code = c.configuration_value');
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_templates', TABLE_TEMPLATES);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_configuration', TABLE_CONFIGURATION);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindValue(':boxes_group', 'left');
        $Qcmsdrag->execute();

        $load_template_id = $Qcmsdrag->value('id');
        //error_log(print_r($Qcmsdrag,TRUE));
        return $load_template_id;
    }}
```

return $load_template_id;
//contains the value that i want to use in the below code

below i am checking if session is set or not, else do the else part.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cms_id']))
    {
        $loadTemplateId = MxpCms_Admin::__construct();
        $MxpBoxesSelected = $MxpCms->getSelectedLayout($loadTemplateId);
        $MxpIdSelected = $MxpCms->getSelectedLayoutId($loadTemplateId);
    }
    else
    {
        $MxpBoxesSelected = $MxpCms->getSelectedLayout($_SESSION['cms_id']);
        $MxpIdSelected = $MxpCms->getSelectedLayoutId($_SESSION['cms_id']);
    }
```

but i get fatal error.

Fatal error:  Non-static method MxpCms_Admin::__construct() cannot be called statically
I am confused on how to return the value.

Comment: You can't return a value from a constructor

Comment: then what am i supposed to do to get the value?
and i know its called automatically by default.

Comment: Write all that under another method and call that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Get Returned Value From Constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730160/php-get-returned-value-from-constructor)

Comment: Use the constructor to set the load_template_id as a class property; and provide a getter method for that property

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran i know i can do that but is there any other way to get that value from constructor

Comment: This is also a case of a constructor doing too much. A constructor should never do "actual work", methods of the instantiated object should do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MxpCms_Admin {

    protected $load_template_id;

    public function __construct()
    {       
        global $MxpDatabase;

        $Qcmsdrag = $MxpDatabase->query('select t.id from :table_templates t, :table_configuration c where t.code = c.configuration_value');
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_templates', TABLE_TEMPLATES);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_configuration', TABLE_CONFIGURATION);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindValue(':boxes_group', 'left');
        $Qcmsdrag->execute();

        $this->load_template_id = $Qcmsdrag->value('id');
        //error_log(print_r($Qcmsdrag,TRUE));
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->load_template_id;
    }
}
```

Then either

```
$Admin = new MxpCms_Admin();
$loadTemplateId = $Admin->getId();
```

or

```
$loadTemplateId = (new MxpCms_Admin())->getId();
```

depending on version of PHP

**Or (even better)**

```
class MxpCms_Admin {

    protected $MxpDatabase;

    public function __construct($MxpDatabase)
    {       
        $this->MxpDatabase = $MxpDatabase;
   }

    public function getId(){
        $Qcmsdrag = $this->MxpDatabase->query('select t.id from :table_templates t, :table_configuration c where t.code = c.configuration_value');
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_templates', TABLE_TEMPLATES);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_configuration', TABLE_CONFIGURATION);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindValue(':boxes_group', 'left');
        $Qcmsdrag->execute();

       return $Qcmsdrag->value('id');
    }
}
```

Then either

```
$Admin = new MxpCms_Admin($MxpDatabase);
$loadTemplateId = $Admin->getId();
```

or

```
$loadTemplateId = (new MxpCms_Admin($MxpDatabase))->getId();
```

Comment: While this does technically answer the question, it's still horrible class design... :)

Comment: @deceze - just doing a bit of refactoring now, starting with DI to eliminate the `global`

Answer (score 0):

```
class MxpCms_Admin {

    protected $mxpDatabase;

    public function __construct($mxpDatabase) {
        $this->mxpDatabase = $mxpDatabase;
    }

    public function getTemplateId() {
        $Qcmsdrag = $this->mxpDatabase->query('select t.id from :table_templates t, :table_configuration c where t.code = c.configuration_value');
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_templates', TABLE_TEMPLATES);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindTable(':table_configuration', TABLE_CONFIGURATION);
        $Qcmsdrag->bindValue(':boxes_group', 'left');
        $Qcmsdrag->execute();

        return $Qcmsdrag->value('id');
    }

}

$admin = new MxpCms_Admin($mxpDatabase);
$templateId = $admin->getTemplateId();
```

This is a more proper use of a class and constructor. I'd argue that the use of the two `TABLE_` constants inside `MxpCms_Admin::getTemplateId` is still bad, since it relies on the global environment instead of dependency injection.

Comment: Looks like we ended up with an identical reworking :)

Comment: There are only so many *sane* ways to do it... Or we're both equally *insane*... :)