# Laravel Views (creator & make)

Tags: php, laravel

I made an view called (`head.blade.php`) and tried to load it in HomeController `__construct` function with `View::make()` function. However, the function works, but not with the variables.

For example, here's function, with `View::make()`:

```
public function __construct() {

  $this->asset = new Asset;

  $assets = array('core');
              $css = $this->asset->generate($assets);

  return View::make('includes.head')->with('styles', $css);  
}
```

If I try to use $styles variable in view, it gives me error: (Undefined variable $styles in...-)

But, digging in Laravel docs I have found this method:

```
public function __construct() {

        $this->asset = new Asset;

        $assets = array('core');

        $css = $this->asset->generate($assets);

        View::creator('includes.head', function($view) use ($css) {
            $view->with('styles', $css);
        });
    }
```

And the method `View::creator` works.

My question is, how and why the `View::make()` doesn't work in `__construct`?

PS. I'm calling the view in another view with `@include` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general OOP, you do not return any value from a constructor.  The implicit return value of a constructor is *the object*.  Remember that the constructor is called whenever a new object is made:

```
$myObject = new MyObject(); // <-- I just called the MyObject constructor
```

Instantiation of a Laravel controller happens *prior* to the dispatching of the route, so returning the View inside the constructor is logically incorrect. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904285/697370).

I'm not sure why you're trying to do this, but I believe it could be because you're trying to attach a 'header' view to all of the views returned by this specific controller.  If so, this isn't the way you do this in Laravel.  To accomplish that, make a layout view that your other views will extend:

```
<!-- app/views/layout/master.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <article>
    @include('layout.header')

    @yield('content')

    @include('layout.footer')
    </article>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- app/views/layout/header.blade.php -->
<header>
    A Header
</header>

<!-- app/views/layout/footer.blade.php -->
<footer>
    A Footer
</footer>

<!-- app/views/some-view.blade.php -->
@extends('layout.master')

@section('content')
View Content
@stop
```

With this setup, `some-view.blade.php` will have both a header and a footer sandwiching the view's main content.

Comment: Thank You for Your reply. :)

Yes that's the one thing I want to try, but also, I want to load my assets from config file, I know there's a way with static function. For example in view I can call:

    @foreach(Asset::generate(array('core')) as $style)
        {{ HTML::style($style) }}
    @endforeach
But, I don't know how secure this is... :/

Comment: in what way are you trying to secure it? the end result of that code is supposedly just link references to stylesheets, so I'm not really sure what your concern would be.

Comment: Alright, I got the idea, I need to think this over again. Thank you  for helping me to get things straight! :)