# What is the use of return $this in php constructors?

Tags: php, constructor

I have always done :

```
class Class1{

   protected $myProperty;

   public function __construct( $property ){

       $this->myProperty = $property;
   }
}
```

But recently, I have been coming across a particular technique like so:

```
class Class2{

   protected $myProperty;

   public function __construct( $property ){

       $this->myProperty = $property;
       return $this;
   }
}
```

And in instantiating this class, one would do :

```
$property = 'some value';

$class1 = new Class1( $property );

$class2 = new Class2( $property );
```

What is the significance of the line `return $this` in the constructor of `Class2` since with or without it, the variable `$class2` will still contain an instance of `Class2`?

Edit : please this is different from a constructor returning values. I heard this one is called fluent interfaces (for method chaining). I have looked at this thread [Constructor returning value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904255/constructor-returning-value). It is not the same thing I am asking. I am asking for the significance of `return $this`

Comment: There is no use. `__constructs()` don't have return values, they always return void.

Comment: To chain method calls (fluent interfaces)

Comment: You don't need to return $this; 
The "new" keyword always return you the object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor returning value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904255/constructor-returning-value)

Comment: I know constructors don't return values.. Which one is correct? @Rizier123 says it is to chain method calls( fluent interfaces). Majority seem to be saying it is pointless. Please help, someone.

Comment: @StephenAdelakun @Rizier123 is right and wrong at the same time. Context is important here. `__constructs()` don't return values, but `return $this` can be used to chain methods.

Comment: @Rizier123 @Andrew there is no point in returning $this from a ctor. if you wanted to chain from a ctor method, you'd have to do `$obj = new Obj(); $obj->__construct()->foo();`. Why would I want to do that?

Comment: @Andrew, `What is the significance of the line return $this in the constructor of Class2 since with or without it, the variable $class2 will still contain an instance of Class2?` I have already made it clear in my question that the variable contains an instance of the class without `return $this`

Comment: @Stephen you don't have to return $this from a ctor in order to chain from it. You can simply do `(new Class2(1))->getMyProperty();`. On side note: Method Chaining and Fluent Interface is two different things. One can use Method Chaining to implement a Fluent Interface, but Method Chaining on it's own has no greater semantics in the chained calls, whereas Fluent Interfaces do, e.g. `$obj->setFoo()->setBar()` is Method Chaining. `$obj->select("…")->from("…")->where(…)` is a Fluent Interface used to build an internal Domain Specific Language.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a use for returning `$this` there.

Chances are that they are using a IDE which automatically inserts `return $this` or similar, which is useful for method chaining, but the return statement to `__construct` is discarded.

Comment: The developers who used it did it intentionally, not inserted by IDE.

Comment: @StephenAdelakun - then they did it pointlessly; because with or without, it makes absolutely no difference..... but if you know that they did it intentionally, then perhaps ask them why!

Answer (score 2):

`return $this;` should not have any value in the constructor. But I see some value if it is returned in any other function for the class, when you want to call the functions consecutively. For example :

```
class Student {
   protected $name;

   public function __construct($name) {
      $this->name = $name;
      //return $this; (NOT NEEDED)
   }

   public function readBook() {
      echo "Reading...";
      return $this;
   }

   public function writeNote() {
      echo "Writing...";
      return $this;
   }

}

$student = new Student("Tareq"); //Here the constructor is called. But $student will get the object, whether the constructor returns it or not.
$student->readBook()->writeNote(); //The readBook function returns the object by 'return $this', so you can call writeNote function from it.
```