# How to show table values in php using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to show table values from database by using PDO but while doing this it shows an **error**

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined method ManageUsers::fetchAll()"

Please provide solution to solve this?

**list-seller.php**

```
<?php
include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.ManageUsers.php";
$sellers = new ManageUsers();
//$sellers->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

while ($row = $sellers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['company_name']; ?>&nbsp;
      <span class="pull-right-container">
      <small class="label pull-center bg-green">Premium Member</small>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['count_free']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['count_travel']; ?>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
      <small class="label pull-center bg-green">Paid</small>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td><a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm disabled">Already Paid</button></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**class.ManageUsers.php**

```
<?php
class ManageUsers{
  include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.database.php";
  public $link;

  function __construct(){
  $db_connection = new dbConnection();
  $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
  return $this->link;

  }

  function seller_list($result){
  $result = $this->link->prepare("SELECT company_name,email,phone,count_free,count_travel FROM login");
  $result->execute();
  }
}
?>
```

**class.database.php**

```
<?php 

class dbConnection{
            protected $db_conn;
            public $db_name='company';
            public $db_user='root';
            public $db_pass='';
            public $db_host='localhost';

            function connect (){
                try{
                    $this->db_conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,  
                                            $this->db_pass);
                    return $this->db_conn;
                   }
                   catch(PDOException $e){
                       return $e->getMessage();
                       echo 'errorrrrrrrr';

                        }
                }

    }


?>
```

Comment: well there is no fetchAll in `ManageUsers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Changes***

**1)** Remove `include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.database.php";` from class ManageUsers (inside) and place it above.

**2)** Add public before `seller_list()`.

**3)** call `seller_list()` in **list-seller.php** page.

**4)** Missed `return` keyword in function `seller_list()`. Add it.

**5)** Remove `$result` from `seller_list()` function in `Class ManageUsers` as it is of no use.

***Updated Code***

**list-seller.php**

```
<?php
include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.ManageUsers.php";
$sellers = new ManageUsers();

$query = $sellers->seller_list();
foreach($query as $row){
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['company_name']; ?>&nbsp;
      <span class="pull-right-container">
      <small class="label pull-center bg-green">Premium Member</small>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['mobile']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['count_free']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['count_travel']; ?>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
      <small class="label pull-center bg-green">Paid</small>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td><a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm disabled">Already Paid</button></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**class.ManageUsers.php**

```
<?php
include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.database.php";
class ManageUsers{

  public $link;

  function __construct(){
    $db_connection = new dbConnection();
    $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
  }

  public function getDB(){
    return $this->link;
  }

  public function seller_list(){
    $result = $this->getDB()->prepare("SELECT company_name,email,phone,count_free,count_travel FROM login");
    $result->execute();
    return $result->fetchAll();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object error appears

Comment: Still Not Working same error as "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object error appears" :(@Nana Partykar

Comment: Paste your DB connection file in your question @user1

Comment: Thanks Bro! It Works!!!:)

Comment: Whoever downvoting please give valid reason. Since you didn't liked my answer or there may be any flaws, So, have GUTS to provide correct answer. **Don't Simply Downvote & Escape.** I give my whole effort to help user as much as possible. Even OP @user1 problem got solved. Then, I don't think anyone having any problem related to it. ~ *Disgusting Behaviour*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a sql query which shows data from table. Try to add these lines in list-seller.php after `$sellers = new ManageUsers();`:

```
$sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
$sellers->query($sql);
while ($row = $sellers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
```

Comment: I already add query in $result in class.ManageUsers.php...so how can i get this ($result) into a list-seller.php

Comment: nlo, add this in seller.php

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a given class can only return instance of said class, no other return value.
See [Constructor returning value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904255/constructor-returning-value)

I'd suggest this instead for your class:

```
class ManageUsers
{
    include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.database.php";

    private $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $db_connection=new dbConnection();
        $this->link=$db_connection->connect();
    }

    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }
```

And use the last function.

```
//list-seller.php//
<?php
include "C:/wamp/www/Super_Admin_MangoAir/classes/class.ManageUsers.php";

$manager = new ManageUsers();
$sellers = $manager->getLink();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `return $this->link` from your constructor and call fetchAll using `$sellers->link->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll()....