# Object Class Cannot Converted to String | Puzzle Game in PHP (about inheritance & construct)

Tags: php, oop, command-line-interface, construct

I have a puzzle for you all.

here is it:

```
class Satu
{
    function __construct(){
        return "satu";
    }
}

class Dua extends Satu
{
    function __construct(){
        return "dua";
    }
}

class Tiga extends Dua
{
    function __construct(){
        return "tiga";
    }
}
$tiga = new Tiga();
echo($tiga);
```

So, when i was ran this file, i got an error. Here is it :

```
PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class Tiga could not be converted to string in C:\Users\habie\Desktop\tigaangka.php on line 48(referred echo($iga)).
```

My questions are:

1. what happened with my code?
2. What is the output code if it is has no error code?

Thank you all :)

Comment: Returning anything from `__construct` doesn't do anything.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904255/constructor-returning-value

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Satu
{
    function __construct(){
        return "satu";
    }
}

class Dua extends Satu
{
    function __construct(){
        return "dua";
    }
}

class Tiga extends Dua
{
    function __construct(){
        return "tiga";
    }
}
$tiga = new Tiga();
print_r($tiga); //Changes here
```

**OutPut**:

```
Tiga Object ( )
```