# Extending DateInterval() as a class object

Tags: php, constructor, dateinterval

I'm trying to migrate some code from Pear Date_span to php and so want to create a class which returns a DateInterval object with zero date and time. I need a class so that I can code a number of methods to the class. However I cannot seem to get this to work. I admit that I am a little new to php, so forgive me. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

```
class myDateSpan {
    public function __construct() {
        return DateInterval::createFromDateString('0 day');
    }

    public function getClock() {
        return $this->format('H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that class constructors return values [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904255/constructor-returning-value) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class) for more on this...

Comment: You'll need to [extend](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php) the class and make sure your `__construct` function definition matches.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a property on your class which holds a `DateInterval` object which you can interact with. Then have a function `getDateInterval` which would return it (if it's not public)

Comment: Thanks for responses so far. Yes I agree, extending dateInterval() would seem the logical way, but it seems you cannot extend this class. I get an error when I try. Having a function to extract the object would unfortunately defeat the purpose. I need to seriously rethink this if it's not possible. Thanks anyway.