# php class access variable

Tags: php

I have the following PHP class:

```
class connect {

public function __construct() {

$sql = new mysqli(...);

return $sql;

}
```

(Of course, this is not the whole code, just to give you the idea.

I then have:

```
class two {

public function validateInput($input) {

$dbconn = new connect();

return $dbconn->real_escape_string($input);
```

}

However, this generates an error. How can I call the real_escape_string method on the $sql variable from class connect?

Cheers!

PS: Update, the error is Fatal error: Call to undefined method connect::real_escape_string()

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class-php

Answer (score 3):

Constructors cannot return values; the return value is implied (a new object instance).

In your example, `$dbconn` is an object of class `connect`. It's not an object of class `mysqli`, so it doesn't have a `real_escape_string` method. The `return $sql` statement has no effect, because it doesn't make sense.

You might have meant to extend `mysqli` (which would be a pain because of all the constructor arguments that you have to forward), or to expose a `mysqli` member instead.

Answer (score 2):

Class connect is going to return an instance of connect and not mysqli.  Maybe try:

```
class connect extends mysqli {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(..);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something more like:

```
class connect {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->sql = new mysqli(...);
    }

    public function real_escape_string($string) {
        // Process $string using $this->sql;
        return $string
    }
}

class two {
    public function validateInput($input) {
        $dbconn = new connect();

        return $dbconn->real_escape_string($input);
    }
}
```