# Class constructor error on validation

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am developing a file uploaded class, and trying to perform few validation before other codes, but its returning all vars instead of false, check following code....

```
class FileUploader
{

   private $filePath;

   function __construct($file_path) {

      if(file_exists($file_path)) {

           $this->filePath = $file_path;

      }

     else return false;

   }

}
```

When I am using this class like following....

```
$file_path = getcwd().'\img.pn'; //invalid path

$file_uploader = new FileUploader($file_path);

if($file_uploader) {
    //process
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid File Path!';
}
```

But it doesn't echo `Invalid File Path` as expected, when i tried `var_dump`, it returned following output...

```
  object(FileUploader)[1]
  private 'filePath' => null
```

Please help to fix this. thanks.

Comment: A constructor should not return anything,use exception instead. Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class-php)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an exception in the constructor as constructors should no return anything. (Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class-php)).
Otherwise you may create a function to check the file_path :

```
class FileUploader
{

   private $filePath;

   function __construct($file_path) {
      $this->filePath = $file_path;
   }



   function isValidFilePath() {
      return file_exists($this->file_path);
   }

}
```

and then :

```
$file_path = getcwd().'\img.pn'; //invalid path

$file_uploader = new FileUploader($file_path);

if($file_uploader->isValidFilePath()) {
    //process
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid File Path!';
}
```