# Having trouble detecting 'return false'

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that can return FALSE.

For some weird reason, I am unable to detect the FALSE return. 
I can detect any other return value without any trouble.

Dumbed down version....

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$run = new myClass();//class returns false
$response = $run->myMethod();
```

I've tested with the following...

```
!$response
!isset($response)
empty($response)
$response == false
$response === false
```

I'm unable to get any type of reaction for any of the conditions I'm familiar with.

If I set the return to 1 or ANYTHING other than false, $response will contain whatever the class returns. 
It's not like this is my first day. (it's my 2nd).

I use return false; frequently and have never had any trouble until today.

Certainly I can fix this by returning something like 'wtf' and test for that condition, but I'd really like to figure out what I'm missing here.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you done a var_dump of your response variable to see exactly what it's returning? This isn't rocket science...

Comment: What you get if you do gettype($response)?

Comment: `var_dump($response)` will answer your question. It's not a good idea to return anything other than an object from a constructor...

Comment: Both var_dump() && gettype() return exactly the same thing.... nothing. No visible data of any type in the browser window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a value in constructor function of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class)

Comment: I edited the question. I am not calling the constructor, I am calling a method in the class.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a instance of your class it will always your return a object not the return of the construct.

```
<?php
class SomeClass
{
    // construct function that will always return false
    public function __construct()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class TestClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturn()
    {
         // check if this code returns false
         $this->assertFalse(new SomeClass);
    }

    public function testAssert()
    {
        // Checks if the object return is actually of SomeClass
        $this->assertInstanceOf('SomeClass', new SomeClass);
    }

    public function testReturnOfConstruct()
    {
        //checks the return of the construct
        $object = new SomeClass;
        $this->assertFalse($object->__construct());
    }
}
```

Return of phpunit

```
phpunit --debug test3.php
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.


Starting test 'TestClass::testReturn'.
F
Starting test 'TestClass::testAssert'.
.
Starting test 'TestClass::testReturnOfConstruct'.
.

Time: 7 ms, Memory: 5.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) TestClass::testReturn
Failed asserting that SomeClass Object () is false.

/var/www/test3.php:14

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: You might want to explain what this does a bit more. PHPUnit-based code might be a bit advanced for this answer. Nice demonstration, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to return false from within `public function __construct()` or `public function MyClass()`*?  This won't work as the `new MyClass()` call will either trigger a PHP error, or return an instance of `MyClass`, which is never going to evaluate to false because it is an instance of an object and thus not false.

If your class does not need to be instantiated to function, you can create a static method to perform the logic you are trying to run like so:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    const COLOUR_BLUE = 'blue';

    public static function isSkyBlue()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['sky']) && $_POST['sky'] == self::COLOUR_BLUE) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// Call doThings() statically to get its value
$response = MyClass::isSkyBlue();
if ($response === false) {
    // Your logic goes here
}
```

Alternatively, if you are passing things to the constructor before it performs its logic, you can do the following:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    const COLOUR_BLUE = 'blue';

    protected $otherObject = null;

    public function __construct($otherObject)
    {
        $this->otherObject = $otherObject;
    }

    public function isSkyBlue()
    {
        if ($this->otherObject->sky == self::COLOUR_BLUE) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// Call doThings() statically to get its value
$response = new MyClass($otherObject)
if ($response->isSkyBlue() === false) {
    // Your logic goes here
}
```

`*` Note that your constructor should always be called `__construct()` as using the class name for the constructor has been deprecated since PHP 5.

Comment: The method I'm calling is not the constructor. It's just a public function. And I'm doing just what you're showing. return X else return false;

Comment: `$response = new MyClass();` will just instantiate the class. You need to then call the method on the class to get your actual response, eg: `$myClass = new MyClass(); $response = $myClass->myMethod();`

Comment: TWW. edited my question. sorry. good catch. But yes... I am instantiating the class and calling the method in the class.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code, please? My guess is that there's an error elsewhere in the logic.

Comment: this is a class that I have used for a while now.
It's just like your example here above. 
     
     if ($this->otherObject->sky == self::COLOUR_BLUE) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;//cannot detect
        return 1;//can detect
        return 0;//can detect
        return 'wtf';//can detect
      }

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a constructor, it wont return anything...it is not a normal function