# PHP extended class

Tags: php

I am rewriting some of my code for PHP 7 compatibility.
While most classes I rewrote work fine, I am having an issue with the extended classes that try to access functions from the original(parent) class, and wondering what I am doing wrong.

This is the main class:

```
  class tableBlock {
    var $table_border = '0';
    var $table_width = '100%';
    var $table_cellspacing = '0';
    var $table_cellpadding = '2';
    var $table_parameters = '';
    var $table_row_parameters = '';
    var $table_data_parameters = '';

//function tableBlock($contents) { // modified for php 7 compatibility
    function __construct($contents) {
      $tableBox_string = '';

      $form_set = false;
      if (isset($contents['form'])) {
        $tableBox_string .= $contents['form'] . "\n";
        $form_set = true;
        array_shift($contents);
      }

      $tableBox_string .= '<table border="' . $this->table_border . '" width="' . $this->table_width . '" cellspacing="' . $this->table_cellspacing . '" cellpadding="' . $this->table_cellpadding . '"';
      if (tep_not_null($this->table_parameters)) $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_parameters;
      $tableBox_string .= '>' . "\n";

      for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($contents); $i<$n; $i++) {
        $tableBox_string .= '  <tr';
        if (tep_not_null($this->table_row_parameters)) $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_row_parameters;
        if (isset($contents[$i]['params']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i]['params'])) $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $contents[$i]['params'];
        $tableBox_string .= '>' . "\n";

        if (isset($contents[$i][0]) && is_array($contents[$i][0])) {
          for ($x=0, $y=sizeof($contents[$i]); $x<$y; $x++) {
            if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['text']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['text'])) {
              $tableBox_string .= '    <td';
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['align']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['align'])) $tableBox_string .= ' align="' . $contents[$i][$x]['align'] . '"';
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['params']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['params'])) {
                $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $contents[$i][$x]['params'];
              } elseif (tep_not_null($this->table_data_parameters)) {
                $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_data_parameters;
              }
              $tableBox_string .= '>';
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['form']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['form'])) $tableBox_string .= $contents[$i][$x]['form'];
              $tableBox_string .= $contents[$i][$x]['text'];
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['form']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['form'])) $tableBox_string .= '</form>';
              $tableBox_string .= '</td>' . "\n";
            }
          }
        } else {
          $tableBox_string .= '    <td';
          if (isset($contents[$i]['align']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i]['align'])) $tableBox_string .= ' align="' . $contents[$i]['align'] . '"';
          if (isset($contents[$i]['params']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i]['params'])) {
            $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $contents[$i]['params'];
          } elseif (tep_not_null($this->table_data_parameters)) {
            $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_data_parameters;
          }
          $tableBox_string .= '>' . $contents[$i]['text'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        }

        $tableBox_string .= '  </tr>' . "\n";
      }

      $tableBox_string .= '</table>' . "\n";

      if ($form_set == true) $tableBox_string .= '</form>' . "\n";

      return $tableBox_string;
    }
  }
```

This is the extended class:

```
class box extends tableBlock {
//    function box() {  // modified for php 7 compatibility
    function __construct() {
      $this->heading = array();
      $this->contents = array();
    }


function menuBox($heading, $contents) {

    global $menu_dhtml;              // add for dhtml_menu
    if ($menu_dhtml == false ) {     // add for dhtml_menu

      $this->table_data_parameters = 'class="menuBoxHeading"';
      if ($heading[0]['link']) {
        $this->table_data_parameters .= ' onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'hand\'" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . $heading[0]['link'] . '\'"';
        $heading[0]['text'] = '&nbsp;<a href="' . $heading[0]['link'] . '" class="menuBoxHeadingLink">' . $heading[0]['text'] . '</a>&nbsp;';
      } else {
        $heading[0]['text'] = '&nbsp;' . $heading[0]['text'] . '&nbsp;';
      }
      $this->heading = $this->tableBlock($heading);

      $this->table_data_parameters = 'class="menuBoxContent"';
      $this->contents = $this->tableBlock($contents);
      return $this->heading . $this->contents . $dhtml_contents;
// ## add for dhtml_menu
    } else {
      $selected = substr(strrchr ($heading[0]['link'], '='), 1);
      $dhtml_contents = $contents[0]['text'];
      $change_style = array ('<br>'=>' ','<BR>'=>' ', 'a href='=> 'a class="menuItem" href=','class="menuBoxContentLink"'=>' ');
      $dhtml_contents = strtr($dhtml_contents,$change_style);
      $dhtml_contents = '<div id="'.$selected.'Menu" class="menu" onmouseover="menuMouseover(event)">'. $dhtml_contents . '</div>';
      return $dhtml_contents;
      }
// ## eof add for dhtml_menu
    }
}
```

As you can see, I modified the constructors to be `__construct`, but the extended functions errors when it tries to access `$this->contents = $this->tableBlock($heading);` and `$this->contents = $this->tableBlock($contents);`

I tried to modify those lines, using `$this->contents = parent::__construct($contents);` and `$this->contents = parent::__construct($heading);` but I am probably writing this wrong as it doesn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `tableBlock` is a method. Does it exist in your classes?

Comment: it did exist in the parent class, but I changed its name to `__construct` as you can see above

Comment: this line `//function tableBlock($contents) { // modified for php 7 compatibility` and the following is the modified line

Comment: Try by making `__constuct` as `public function __construct($contents)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__construct` function is meant to construct the object, which means it is there to create the object in memory and initialize some properties (if you need this). You have used this correctly in your extended class. 
However, you cannot return a value from the constructor: [Returning a value in constructor function of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class)

I would recommend to rename your `__construct` function again to something like `createTableBlock` and call this function from your extended class with `parent::createTableBlock($arguments)`.

Also I would recommend to always call your parent constructor (if there is any). You can accomplish this by calling `parent::__construct` in the constructor of the extended class.

As request by OP his code rewritten:

```
  class tableBlock {
    var $table_border = '0';
    var $table_width = '100%';
    var $table_cellspacing = '0';
    var $table_cellpadding = '2';
    var $table_parameters = '';
    var $table_row_parameters = '';
    var $table_data_parameters = '';

    function __construct() {
      //empty
    }

    function tableBlock($contents) {
      $tableBox_string = '';

      $form_set = false;
      if (isset($contents['form'])) {
        $tableBox_string .= $contents['form'] . "\n";
        $form_set = true;
        array_shift($contents);
      }

      $tableBox_string .= '<table border="' . $this->table_border . '" width="' . $this->table_width . '" cellspacing="' . $this->table_cellspacing . '" cellpadding="' . $this->table_cellpadding . '"';
      if (tep_not_null($this->table_parameters)) $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_parameters;
      $tableBox_string .= '>' . "\n";

      for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($contents); $i<$n; $i++) {
        $tableBox_string .= '  <tr';
        if (tep_not_null($this->table_row_parameters)) $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_row_parameters;
        if (isset($contents[$i]['params']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i]['params'])) $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $contents[$i]['params'];
        $tableBox_string .= '>' . "\n";

        if (isset($contents[$i][0]) && is_array($contents[$i][0])) {
          for ($x=0, $y=sizeof($contents[$i]); $x<$y; $x++) {
            if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['text']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['text'])) {
              $tableBox_string .= '    <td';
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['align']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['align'])) $tableBox_string .= ' align="' . $contents[$i][$x]['align'] . '"';
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['params']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['params'])) {
                $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $contents[$i][$x]['params'];
              } elseif (tep_not_null($this->table_data_parameters)) {
                $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_data_parameters;
              }
              $tableBox_string .= '>';
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['form']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['form'])) $tableBox_string .= $contents[$i][$x]['form'];
              $tableBox_string .= $contents[$i][$x]['text'];
              if (isset($contents[$i][$x]['form']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i][$x]['form'])) $tableBox_string .= '</form>';
              $tableBox_string .= '</td>' . "\n";
            }
          }
        } else {
          $tableBox_string .= '    <td';
          if (isset($contents[$i]['align']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i]['align'])) $tableBox_string .= ' align="' . $contents[$i]['align'] . '"';
          if (isset($contents[$i]['params']) && tep_not_null($contents[$i]['params'])) {
            $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $contents[$i]['params'];
          } elseif (tep_not_null($this->table_data_parameters)) {
            $tableBox_string .= ' ' . $this->table_data_parameters;
          }
          $tableBox_string .= '>' . $contents[$i]['text'] . '</td>' . "\n";
        }

        $tableBox_string .= '  </tr>' . "\n";
      }

      $tableBox_string .= '</table>' . "\n";

      if ($form_set == true) $tableBox_string .= '</form>' . "\n";

      return $tableBox_string;
    }
  }
```

This is the extended class:

```
class box extends tableBlock {
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct(); //calling parent constructor
      $this->heading = array();
      $this->contents = array();
    }


function menuBox($heading, $contents) {
    global $menu_dhtml;              // add for dhtml_menu
    if ($menu_dhtml == false ) {     // add for dhtml_menu

      $this->table_data_parameters = 'class="menuBoxHeading"';
      if ($heading[0]['link']) {
        $this->table_data_parameters .= ' onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'hand\'" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . $heading[0]['link'] . '\'"';
        $heading[0]['text'] = '&nbsp;<a href="' . $heading[0]['link'] . '" class="menuBoxHeadingLink">' . $heading[0]['text'] . '</a>&nbsp;';
      } else {
        $heading[0]['text'] = '&nbsp;' . $heading[0]['text'] . '&nbsp;';
      }
      $this->heading = $this->tableBlock($heading);

      $this->table_data_parameters = 'class="menuBoxContent"';
      $this->contents = $this->tableBlock($contents);
      return $this->heading . $this->contents . $dhtml_contents;
// ## add for dhtml_menu
    } else {
      $selected = substr(strrchr ($heading[0]['link'], '='), 1);
      $dhtml_contents = $contents[0]['text'];
      $change_style = array ('<br>'=>' ','<BR>'=>' ', 'a href='=> 'a class="menuItem" href=','class="menuBoxContentLink"'=>' ');
      $dhtml_contents = strtr($dhtml_contents,$change_style);
      $dhtml_contents = '<div id="'.$selected.'Menu" class="menu" onmouseover="menuMouseover(event)">'. $dhtml_contents . '</div>';
      return $dhtml_contents;
      }
// ## eof add for dhtml_menu
    }
}
```

Now call the parent logic with `$this->contents = parent::tableBlock($contents);`

Comment: Agree with @Florian Moser but instead on returning you can assign your data to the variable directly as `$this->contents = $tableBox_string` 
But again constructor is just for object initialization put your logic in different function as suggested on above answer.

Comment: Do you mean rename the `function __construct`in the parent class or the extended class? And if I do that and it has a different name than the class, ie. `class tableBlock` but `function createTableBlock` - won't this function stop being a constructor?

Comment: @CreativeMind rename it in the parent class. and you are right, it will stop being the constructor. You will have to call the function from your extended class.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. Can you please provide a detailed example using my code, my 2 classes?

Comment: @CreativeMind I've just did, check it out.

Comment: Thanks. So eventually you didn't rename the `__construct` function again to something like `createTableBlock`, but instead you reverted it back to `tableBlock` and then added an empty function `__construct` above it. Then you called that empty function `__construct`  from the extended class. right? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Thank you so much! :) It's much better than renaming the method, as it was breaking my entire application

Answer (score 0):

__construct never return value, you should use method instead of return value in construct.