# PHP Have Object Return Different Object

Tags: php, oop, reference, instance

In a few different places I call:

```
$model=NEW MakeCall($form);
```

I have updated the `MakeCall` class with several changes that I want to take affect after a given date. I renamed the original class `MakeCallOld`

How can I leave my calls to:

```
$model=NEW MakeCall($form);
```

intact and within `MakeCall` do this:

```
class MakeCall
{ ...

    public function __construct($form)
    {
        //Use Legacy MakeCallOld for stuff before 2016-10-01
        if ($form['date']<'2016-10-01') {
            $object=NEW MakeCallOld($form);
            return $object;
        }

        $this->perform several functions and set variables...
```

This currently just returns an empty object of class `MakeCallOld` but it does not appear to run the constructor in `MakeCallOld` as all properties are empty. I would just like the entire object of `MakeCallOld` dropped into `$model`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a value in constructor function of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class)

Comment: You want a Factory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a static factory constructor. This is the way you should be doing it to add initialization logic or switch constructors depending on the argument.

```
class MakeCall
{

    public function __construct($form)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
    }

    public function showForm(){
        echo $this->form;
    }


    public static function create($form){
        //put logic for picking object or whatever here!
        $object = new MakeCall($form);
        //Do more initializing if you want here!
        return $object;

    }
}

$form = "asdasd";
$model= MakeCall::create($form);
$model->showForm();
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors don't have a return value, so by saying `return $object` you are simply ending the control flow there and doing nothing else, never reaching "perform several functions and set variables". Depending on your structure you should consider making `MakeCall` inherit from `MakeCallOld`, then you can simply call `parent::__construct();` in `MakeCall`'s constructor.