# How to use PDO connection in other classes?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I think I've a problem in understanding how OOP works. I already changed the code that it works, but it isn't the propper way I think. Following scenario (No, I'm not creating a userlogin by myself, its really just for local dev. to understand OOP better):

I've a database.php file:

```
class Database {

    /* Properties */
    private $conn;
    private $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $password = '';

    /* Creates database connection */
    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "";
            die();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

So in this class I'm creating a database connection and I return the connection (object?)

Then I have a second class, the famous User class (actually I'm not using autoload, but I know about it):

```
include "database.php";

class User {
    /* Properties */
    private $conn;

    /* Get database access */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = new Database();
    }

    /* Login a user */
    public function login() {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT username, usermail FROM user");
        if($stmt->execute()) {
            while($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $fetch[] = $rows;
            }
            return $fetch;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So thatare my two classes. Nothing big, as you see. Now, don't get confued about the function name `login` - Actually I just try to select some usernames and usermails from database and displaying them. I try to achieve this by:

```
$user = new User();
$list = $user->login();

foreach($list as $test) {
    echo $test["username"];
}
```

And here comes the problem. When I execute this code, I get the following error message:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare()

And I'm not sure that I really understand what causes this error.

**The code works well when I change the following things:**

Change `$conn` in database.php to public instead of private (I think thats bad...? But when its private, I can only execute querys inside of the Database class, I'm right? So should I put all these querys in the Database class? I think that's bad, because in a big project it will get become really big..)

And the second change I've to do is:
Change `$this->conn->prepare` to `$this->conn->conn->prepare` in the user.php file. And here I've really no Idea why.

I mean, in the constructor of the `user.php` I've a `$this->conn = new Database()` and since new Database will return me the connection object from DB class, I really don't know why there have to be a second `conn->`

Comment: The constructor shouldn't return anything : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849572/returning-a-value-in-constructor-function-of-a-class - to have access to that method your `Database` class would need to extend `PDO`

Comment: Your error is `$this->conn->prepare(` you're trying to call the prepare function on your Database class but there is no prepare function. you could make the `$conn` of Database public which would result in `$this->conn->conn->prepare`. the return value of your Database `__construct()` is returning a Database object not the connection even if you `retrun $this->conn`

Comment: @CD001 Thanks for the advise about the constructor, I'll take a look at it. Sure about the second point? Because when I put the whole `login` function in the database class, it works perfectly, without to extend from PDO...

Comment: that's right, because in your `Database` class `conn` is `PDO` instance and has such capabilities

Comment: @Twinfriends yea I'm sure.. If you put the Login into the Database class, `$this->conn` is the PDO object of Database, not the Database object itself

Comment: Inside the database class you'd be calling `$this->conn` - in which case that *is* a PDO instance so the method exists and you're good. When you instantiate `Database` however from outside, you're creating a new `Database` object which only has the methods you define - unless you extend another class.

Comment: $this->con = (new Database())->con; Not really advisable to do it this way but it allows you to directly access the connection with $this->con->query();

Comment: @CD001 Oohh it start to make sense! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Do not create classes such as your `Database` class as it's rather useless. It would make sense to create a database wrapper if it adds some extra functionality to PDO. But given its current code, better to use vanilla PDO instead.
- Create a **single** $db instance from either vanilla PDO or your database class.
- **Pass it as a constructor parameter** into every class that needs a database connection

database.php:

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

user.php

```
<?php
class User {
    /* Properties */
    private $conn;

    /* Get database access */
    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
        $this->conn = $pdo;
    }

    /* List all users */
    public function getUsers() {
        return $this->conn->query("SELECT username, usermail FROM user")->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

app.php

```
include 'database.php';
$user = new User($pdo);
$list = $user->getUsers();

foreach($list as $test) {
    echo $test["username"],"\n";
}
```

output:

```
username_foo
username_bar
username_baz
```

Check out my [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) for more PDO details.

Comment: While this is a nice way to solve it, I personally don't like to have the connection in my models. Might aswell to keep it "clean" extend a Base model which contains the connection methods.

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden if you extend a Base model, then you have the connection in the offspring class as well.

Comment: That's right but what i meant is your Child model will be "clean" in the sense of readability that it doesn't clog up with extra methods and variables. One way or another the only true way you wont have them in your model is using a static database class, but yeah not the proper way to do it.

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden if you want your classes to be clean look for the Data Mapper pattern.

Comment: If I have 3 objects that share the same db connection in the same iteration is a bad thing?

Comment: In class User (properties), shouldn't it be `private $pdo;` instead of `private $conn;` ?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner nope, it shouldn't. $pdo is a local variable for the constructor and conn is a class variable.