# Multiple or one shared PDO database object

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, resources

I have class, which takes care of DB connection and queries, using PDO. Another classes uses it's methods to connect database, fetch or insert data. My question is;

Do you think it is better to init one database object and share as global var (interference?), or make a child class which inherits it's methods (so for every class new connection object is made)?

Using child class:

```
class database{
  public function __construct(){
    //connect database, save object to $this->con, catch exeptions
  }

  public function query($query, $data){
    //prepare query, insert data, $this->con->exec(), return result
  }

  public function insert($tablename, $data){
    //prepare insert query from assoc array in $data to $tablename and return PDO::statement
  }

  public function update($tablename, $query, $data){
    //prepare update $query with given assoc array $data placeholder replaced for $tablename and return bool
  }

  public function delete($tablename, $query, $data = array()){
    //prepare delete query, exec and return bool
  }
}

class user extends database{
  function register($data){
    $this->insert('users', array(
      'username' => 'abcdef',
      'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
    ));
  }

  function login($uname, $upass){
    //blahblah
  }
}

class content extends database{
  //...
}

//more classes
$db = new database();
$user = new user();
```

If I init e.g. $db = new Database(); and $user = new user(); there are two opened connections at once.

Using shared object (same code as above, except extending)

```
class database{
  public function __construct(){
    //connect database, save object to $this->con, catch exeptions
  }

  public function query($query, $data){
    //prepare query, insert data, $this->con->exec(), return result
  }

  public function insert($tablename, $data){
    //prepare insert query from assoc array in $data to $tablename and return PDO::statement
  }

  public function update($tablename, $query, $data){
    //prepare update $query with given assoc array $data placeholder replaced for $tablename and return bool
  }

  public function delete($tablename, $query, $data = array()){
    //prepare delete query, exec and return bool
  }
}

class user{
  public function __construct($con){
    $this->con = $con;
  }

  function register($data){
    $this->insert('users', array(
      'username' => 'abcdef',
      'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
    ));
  }

  function login($uname, $upass){
    //blahblah
  }
}

class content{
  public function __construct($con){
    $this->con = $con;
  }
  //...
}
$db = new database();
$user = new user($db);
```

This case uses one object, but I'm not sure, it won't be problem, if there are mixed commands for different actions

```
$user->login();
$content->add();
$user->logout();
$stats->newReport();
```

What do you think? Also there may be some resource differences (memory for keeping objects, processor load) Thanks in advance

Comment: From OO design point of view - a user does not extend a database, it uses one.

Comment: I asked a quite similar question once, and I got a really good answer for it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630810/understanding-oop-how-to-use-pdo-connection-in-other-classes

Comment: Well it's possible to extend user from database. But it sounds wrong and it looks like User is a database.. But user is in realitity a table.. class user extends table would be more logical OOP