# Get the ID of the record I just inserted with my query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function:

```
public function insert_task_in_table_finished(int $city_id, string $street, string $phone, string $date, int $price, string $comment, int $operator_id, int $task_id, int $status_id, int $team_id, string $started_on, string $finished_on): int
{
        $connection = $this->get_db_connection();

        $stmt = $connection->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO "
            . "`tasks_finished`"
            . "(`city_id`, `street`, `phone`, `date`, `price`, `comment`, `operator_id`, `task_id`, `status_id`, `team_id`, `started_on`, `finished_on`)"
            . " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $stmt->execute([$city_id, $street, $phone, $date, $price, $comment, $operator_id, $task_id, $status_id, $team_id, $started_on, $finished_on]);
        $result = $stmt->rowCount();
        $stmt = null;
        return $result;
}
```

What I am looking to do is - get the ID of the element that I have just inserted with this query.

I have done my research and found that there exists `PDO::lastInsertId` function or `mysqli_insert_id` both of which return `id used in the latest query`.

This would seem like something I would need, however, my main concern is the following situation:

Let's say I have many users on my website and few of them decided to finish a task simultaneously so 3 of them press corresponding buttons.

The idea is that each user should receive an `ID` of the task that `He` has finished, but considering that those function return that `ID` of the last inserted row, I think that it is possible that it could lead to a situation where a user receives `ID` of task inserted by someone else in case when there are many simultaneous finishes.

Edit: The questions are:

- For those who have more experience working with PDO/MySQL - is the scenario I described possible?
- If it is, what would be the correct approach to guarantee that each user receives the id of the task that he himself has inserted? (Besides the obvious `SELECT` method)

Edit 2:

Here is how my `get_db_connection()` looks:

```
class DB
{
    private function get_db_connection(): PDO
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=crm;charset=utf8mb4";
        $username = 'root'; // TODO -> replace with proper one when moving to producction
        $password = ''; // TODO -> replace with proper one when moving to producction

        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
        ];

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            exit('Unknown error: PDO Creation');
        }

        return $pdo;
    }
```

All the actions that are related with DB changes are made only through my `repository` which has each function create its own instance of `DB` class and then call `DB` functions from there.

Like this: (2 functions from my `repository`)

```
function get_user_by_id(int $id)
{
    $DB = new DB();
    $user = $DB->select_user_by_id($id);

    if (empty($user)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $user;
}

function create_new_task(string $table, string $street, string $phone, string $date, int $price, string $comment, string $operator_id): bool
{
    $DB = new DB();
    $result = $DB->insert_task_in_table($table, $street, $phone, $date, $price, $comment, $operator_id);

    if (empty($result)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I guess this approach guarantees that each user has his own connection, even more so, each function has its own connection, correct?

Comment: From my knowledge is `PDO::lastInsertId` bound to the pdo (so basicly to the referenced object, in your case its `$stmt`). Maybe someone could confirm that. Otherwise this function would have been pointless (since it would produce random results). Please read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). There are important notes, such as this: *"This method may not return a meaningful or consistent result across different PDO drivers, because the underlying database may not even support the notion of auto-increment fields or sequences."*

Comment: The last insert ID is kept _per connection_, so assuming you have a “normal” setup where each of those requests by your three different users establishes its own database connection, there is nothing to worry about at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: BTW, there is no point in returning the rowCount. It will always return 1 no matter that, hence it's just pointless. You can return said insert id instead

Comment: @CBroe could you please take a look at `Edit 2` I made to my post. I added a bit more information on how everything works in my code.

Comment: yes, this approach guarantees that each function has its own connection and that's what you should absolutely NOT to do.

Comment: see [how to use pdo in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43631201/285587)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: @YourCommonSense one last question I have is: If I make my `get_db_connection` staic and then in each function simply do `self::get_db_connection` I believe that would ensure that I have a single instance that is simply reused, am I correct?

Comment: not at all. static or not static, it creates a new connection every time it's called. Besides, using such a function will be against OOP principles. You have to make your mind, whether your code is OOP or procedural

Comment: @YourCommonSense I got it, cheers

Comment: @YourCommonSense Hello again. I'd like to ask you for an advice. I am looking to learn OOP PHP and I know, there is plenty information online, but since you seem to know PHP quite well, perhaps you could give me some suggestions on where could I start if that isn't too much to ask.

Comment: Hi. I know PHP but I don't know much tutorials. Based on the author's reputation I would recommend this one https://laracasts.com/series/object-oriented-bootcamp-in-php